# for loop C++ Don't stop for Cin

Tags: c++, loops

```
    shipname[0] = "Aircraft";
    shipname[1] = "Battleship";
    shipname[2] = "Destoryer";
    shipname[3] = "Submarine";
    shipname[4] = "Patrol Boat";

    cout << "Do you wish to place your own ships. Y/N ";
    cin >> Isplaceship;


        if ((Isplaceship = "Y") | (Isplaceship = "y"))
        {
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout << "Please Enter a location for your " << shipname[i] << endl;
        cout << "type row. col & direction(0 horizontal, 1 vertical) split by spaces: ";
        cin >> x >> y >> dir;
        cout << "your input is " << x << " " << y << " " << dir;
    }


    cout << endl;

}
    else if ((Isplaceship = "N") | (Isplaceship = "n"))
    {

    };


}
```

So I want to make a battleship game, but in this stage i want the user input their input according the the ship, but it never stop and just display all the result in the shipname. I never can enter any input.

Comment: Can you show a little bit more code?

Comment: Are you sure this `cin >> x >> y >> dir;` line is inside of for loop ?

Comment: Yes it is inside the loop, Sorry I didn't display the code here properly.

Comment: Are you sure that `cin` isn't in fail state at this point?

Comment: Maybe include your whole code. What you're posting should work correctly.

Comment: User input is complicated.  You need to check for errors and such.

Comment: The problem must be related to your input (e.g. leaving `cin` in a broken state as suggested by @πάνταῥεῖ). Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this: `if ((Isplaceship = "Y") | (Isplaceship = "y"))` to this: `if ((Isplaceship == "Y") | (Isplaceship == "y"))`.

Comment: Ahh after, you said that i went to check on my type of my Isplaceship, it was bool before... I now changed to String, now its working, Thank you guys for helping.

Answer (score 3):

I did some coding myself:

```
int i = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; ++i)
{
    cout << "input a number:" << endl;
    cin >> i;
    cout << "The number you input is:" << i << endl;
}
```

And the result is:

```
input a number:
1
The number you input is:1
input a number:
2
The number you input is:2
input a number:
3
The number you input is:3
input a number:
4
The number you input is:4
input a number:
5
The number you input is:5
```

I am not so sure why you would get that result, but I think you can compare my code to yours or do some other similar coding, which may help you figure out some details that you miss.